# How similar are polyembryonic plant siblings to each other?

Tags: genetics, botany, embryology

[image]

I successfully germinated all the seeds I found in a [Yuzu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuzu) fruit. From about half of the seeds there are 2 little plants growing, like in the picture. I understand this is due to the occurence of [polyembryony](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyembryony), which is quite common in the genus Citrus.

My question: Are the two plants growing out of the same seed more closely related (= more genetically similar) than two plants growing out of different seeds (of the same fruit)?